# How to use compiled templates?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I found on StringTemplate pages  some reference to template compilation (http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/compiler/Compiler.html). 
The info is rather, let's say, lapidary.

I cannot find any description/tutorial/example on why and how to use template compilation in ST4. I'd like to take advantage of this feature, as I suspect it could be beneficial to performance.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class is always used by the StringTemplate 4 implementation. Code using the library does not need to manually enable, configure, or interact with it directly.

Comment: Does the compilation improve performance or is it done for other purposes?

Comment: StringTemplate 4 uses a linear bytecode intepreter for rendering instead of an AST-based interpreter (like StringTemplate 3 used). Since there is no alternate implementation of StringTemplate 4 which does not use the bytecode interpreter for rendering, there is no way to directly answer your question. However, StringTemplate 4 does substantially outperform StringTemplate 3, and the improvement is likely due (at least in part) to this difference.